'have got to do' vs. 'have to do' with repeated actions
I still have questions about the difference between 'have got to do' and 'have to do' in case of repeated actions.
I understand that 'have got to' is informal spoken British. But there must be other differences too.
For instance, Ngram Viewer lists no results for 'have got to work every', 'got to go there every', 'got to jump every', and practically no results for 'have got to brush'.  'Have got to attend' is 300 times less common than 'have to attend'. Why?
I understand that Ngram searches through books, but dialogues are found in books too, and this is what baffles me.

There's no difference (apart from personal preference) between I have to go now and I have got to go now. But the longer second form is far less common and far more "colloquial, conversational". Is that what you're asking about? btw - it's only my opinion, but I think Americans are more likely to include got to than Brits in such contexts. And I don't think "repeated action" is a relevant factor here.

Yes, I think you are right in saying that British English speakers tend to use I have to do X for an obligation to do something repeatedly. "I have to get up early every morning" as opposed to "I've got to get up early tomorrow". I don't know why - it's 'just the way we say it'.

@KateBunting Thanks! But what you say contradicts what FumbleFingers has written, and I am even more perplexed now.

English has two present tense forms for have: have/have got. Have got to do something is not just British English at all. With the meaning of obligation, there is no difference at all between: I have to go and I've got to go. BUT: get up is a an additional meaning. However: I've got to get up early and I have to get up early. mean the same exact thing. And it's complicated to explain though I have several posts on this in ELL. And I am an AmE speaker and use both and so do the people I know.

Repeated action, right. That has nothing to do with these uses in the present tense. We are discussing the meaning here of have/have got as an obligation. They are also used to mean: to own or possess. I have a car/I've got a car.

Well, here's the usage chart clearly showing that my suspicion (that AmE is more likely to include got in I have [got] to go now) was correct. Note that I say was correct, because in recent decades BrE has fallen into line with AmE on this one.

In my experience (AUS) I have got to is usually used only for emphasis. Otherwise it is I have to or I've got to.
